# why do I get Error in `vec_as_location()`: when computing count and full join function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I made the objects with the variable name I want and selected variables for imported data. But when i use full_join or count, it kept giving me the Error in `vec_as_location()`:.  Does anyone know how to avoid this error? The code I wrote a month ago also got this error. But a month ago it worked.

```
vars <- c("pidp", "cb_age")

wave1 <- read_dta("./data/dresp_w.dta",
                  col_select = vars)
vars2 <- c("pidp", "cb_sex")

wave2 <- read_dta("./data/dresp_w.dta",
                  col_select = vars2)
wave12 <- full_join(wave1, wave2, by = "pidp")
count(wave1,cb_sex)
```

The output for `dput(head(wave1))` 
`dput(head(wave2))` would be:

```
structure(list(pidp = structure(c(76165, 280165, 599765, 732365, 
1587125, 3424485), label = "Cross-wave Person Identifier (Public Release)", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    cb_age = structure(c(37, 40, 33, 34, 54, 84), label = "Age - derived", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(Missing = -9, 
    Inapplicable = -8, Refusal = -2, `Don't know` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
structure(list(pidp = structure(c(76165, 280165, 599765, 732365, 
1587125, 3424485), label = "Cross-wave Person Identifier (Public Release)", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    cb_sex = structure(c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2), label = "Respondent sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(Missing = -9, 
    Inapplicable = -8, Refusal = -2, `Don't know` = -1, Male = 1, 
    Female = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
    ))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Your column name in the second data is 'cb_sex'.. Thus, `count` is working fine `count(wave2, cb_sex)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
      cb_sex     n
   <dbl+lbl> <int>
1 1 [Male]       1
2 2 [Female]     5`

Comment: Sorry I skipped some data manipulations in the post. But it still doesn't work..The error says: Error in `vec_as_location()`:
! `...` must be empty.
✖ Problematic argument:
• call = call

Comment: Can you show the dput of exact data that show the error because if the structure is different, it would give different behavior `count(wave1,cb_sex)`  wouldn't work because `cb_sex` is column in `wave2`

Comment: do you still get the error?  Can you show the `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: without data manipulation , the output for dput is exact as same as the output in the post. its weird cause last time like a month ago ,I run the same code i didn't get any error.

Comment: Please check if you have updated any of the packages or the R version etc within this period

Comment: ```packageVersion('dplyr')```.     [1] ‘1.0.7’

Comment: I used `1.0.9` though

Comment: Have you loaded `library(haven)`?.  I have `haven_2.4.3` version

Comment: Just updated dplyr packageversion to 1.0.9 and it worked!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine with `dplyr` `packageVersion -1.0.9`

```
dplyr::count(wave2, cb_sex)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
      cb_sex     n
   <dbl+lbl> <int>
1 1 [Male]       1
2 2 [Female]     5
```